# Problems with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I want to put the result of my request in this array, `$dataPoints1 = array`, but it doesn't work.

This is my request:

```
$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(id_etudiant)as nbre1 FROM suivre WHERE n_formation='1'
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(id_etudiant)FROM suivre WHERE n_formation='2'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id_etudiant)FROM suivre 
WHERE n_formation='3'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$dataPoints1 = array( 
    array("y" => ''. $row["nbre1"].'',"label" => "formation1" ),
    array("y" => ''. $row["nbre1"].'',"label" => "formation2" ),
    array("y" => ''. $row["nbre1"].'',"label" => "formation3" ),

);}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to give more details about what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by simplifying your sql

```
SELECT COUNT(id_etudiant)as nbre1, n_formation as formation FROM suivre GROUP BY n_formation;
```

Start by declaring your array outside of your loop then add to the next index by using the "[]".

Try this:

```
$dataPoints1 = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dataPoints1[] = array("y" => $row["nbre1"], "label" => $row['formation'] )
```

or

```
    $dataPoints1[] = $row
}
```

Comment: @kamelberkani it is because your array is expecting another a value. You have for example `array(1,2,3,)` when it should be `array(1,2,3)` the last comma you have is causing your error.

Comment: thank you it works but instead of getting formation 1 2 3 it display (r ) in my bar chart have a message error :Warning: Illegal string offset 'formation' in C:\wamp\www\test1\etudiant.php on line 16, ligne 16: $dataPoints1[] = array("y" => $row["nbre1"], "label" => row['formation']);

Comment: @kamelberkani can you edit your post and show the new code as well please

Comment: here is my new code$sql = "
SELECT COUNT(id_etudiant)as nbre1, formation.nom_formation as formation FROM suivre JOIN formation on suivre.n_formation=formation.n_formation GROUP BY nom_formation ";
 $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
//print_r($result = mysqli_query($link,$sql));
$dataPoints1 = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dataPoints1[] = array("y" => $row["nbre1"], "label" => row['formation']);
 }